# How to get Mysqli Stmt to fetch multiple rows correctly?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I've been reaching the end of my ideas with this crazy problem.

Using mysqli I run the following query

```
SELECT * FROM `shop_cart` WHERE `tmpID`=?
```

It should return each row in an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [tmpID] => af83abab7fdee8eb0cf8919f171cdeec
            [pID] => 800
            [qty] => 2
            [time] => 1310076898
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [tmpID] => af83abab7fdee8eb0cf8919f171cdeec
            [pID] => 797
            [qty] => 1
            [time] => 1310076903
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [tmpID] => af83abab7fdee8eb0cf8919f171cdeec
            [pID] => 883
            [qty] => 1
            [time] => 1310076907
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [tmpID] => af83abab7fdee8eb0cf8919f171cdeec
            [pID] => 795
            [qty] => 1
            [time] => 1310076909
        )

)
```

Instead I get four copies of the same row like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [tmpID] => af83abab7fdee8eb0cf8919f171cdeec
            [pID] => 795
            [qty] => 1
            [time] => 1310076909
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [tmpID] => af83abab7fdee8eb0cf8919f171cdeec
            [pID] => 795
            [qty] => 1
            [time] => 1310076909
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [tmpID] => af83abab7fdee8eb0cf8919f171cdeec
            [pID] => 795
            [qty] => 1
            [time] => 1310076909
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [tmpID] => af83abab7fdee8eb0cf8919f171cdeec
            [pID] => 795
            [qty] => 1
            [time] => 1310076909
        )

)
```

The problem lies somewhere in this bit of code I think:

```
while ($query->fetch()){ 
    $results[] = $fields;
}
```

If I put `print_r($fields)` in like this:

```
while ($query->fetch()){ 
    print_r($fields);
    $results[] = $fields;
}
```

It prints each row of the results correctly. But if I put `print_r($results)` in here like this:

```
while ($query->fetch()){ 
    $results[] = $fields;
}
print_r($results);
```

...then I get one large array containing duplicate copes of only one row. It seems to me that the $results array isn't getting populated correctly. It seems that the data is coming out of the database okay.

Any help would be great, I'm really at the end of my rope at figuring this out!

**Edit**

Here's some more code preceding (and including) the fetch() loop as posted above.

```
// Generate Types
$types = '';                        //initial sting with types
foreach($params as $param) {        //for each element, determine type and add
    if(is_int($param)) {
        $types .= 'i';              //integer
    } elseif (is_float($param)) {
        $types .= 'd';              //double
    } elseif (is_string($param)) {
        $types .= 's';              //string
    } else {
        $types .= 'b';              //blob and unknown
    }
}
array_unshift($params, $types);

$query = $this->connection->stmt_init();
if($query->prepare($sql)) {
    call_user_func_array(array($query,'bind_param'),$this->refValues($params));
    $query->execute(); 

    if($fetch){ // Only if we want to return an array of results
        // Get Metadata
        $meta = $query->result_metadata();

        $fields = $results = array();
        while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) { 
            $var = $field->name; 
            $$var = null; 
            $fields[$var] = &$$var; 
        }

        call_user_func_array(array($query,'bind_result'),$fields);

        while ($query->fetch()){ 
            pr($fields);
            $results[] = $fields;
        }
    }
} else die(printf("Error: %s\n", $this->connection->error.' : '.$this->lastQ));
```

Comment: @zerkms - Okay, hang on a sec and I will add more info to the question

Comment: @zerkms - See the edited question above for more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've worked out a solution. Albeit not a very elegant one, but it works :). I'm just making an array called `$fieldNames` and storing the names of the fields being returned via mysql. Then in the `fetch()` while loop I'm just looping through the `$fieldNames` and setting `$results` from `$fields[$fieldNames]`. The code below might make more sense than I can make by explaining it!

```
$fields = $results = array();
while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) { 
    $var = $field->name; 
    $fields[$var] = &$$var; 
    $fieldNames[] = $var;
}

$fieldCount = count($fieldNames);

call_user_func_array(array($query,'bind_result'),$fields);

$i=0;
while ($query->fetch()){
    $key = $arKey ? $fields[$arKey] : $i;
    for($l=0;$l<$fieldCount;$l++) $results[$key][$fieldNames[$l]] = $fields[$fieldNames[$l]];
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you've declared `$fields` to be a reference somewhere in your code (explicitly or implicitly). Each array element you append to `$results` is actually going to be a copy of that same reference, so each array element points to the same bit of memory in php, which'll happen to be the last row fetched from your query.

I'd suggest doing an `unset($fields)` before you do your variable binding/result fetching, which would break the reference setting on the `$fields` variable.

Comment: Thanks Marc, However, I tried putting `unset($fields);` just before the fetch() loop, but now it just gives me an empty array of the results. I've just posted some more code above which might shed some more light on the problem.

Comment: I think you're right about the reference... but I'm at loss as to how to go about fetching the results if `$fields` isn't referenced...